# Symfony 6.3 oidc token Handler

Tags: symfony, openid-connect, symfony6

i got a question about [OpenIdConnect](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_token.html#using-openid-connect-oidc) in the doc they say

```
By default, the OidcTokenHandler creates an OidcUser with the claims. To create your own User from the claims, you must create your own UserProvider:
```

But when I call any route, I got an error: `"main" firewall requires a user provider but none was defined`.  Like it missing the provider in the seurity.yaml configuration. But since I want to get the `OidcUser` provide by default I don't want to create my own UserProvider.

There is a configuration to do. or a service to define as provider to get the `OidcUser` ?

This is my current security.yaml configuration:

```yaml
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    firewalls:
        main:
            access_token:
                token_handler:
                    oidc_user_info: https://keycloack.doamin.xxx/realms/Api/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Without the actual contents of your `security.yaml` file, we are unable to help you or write up a helpfull answer. In addition, have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), where you can find more usefull tips to provide more background information that can be useful for other readers.

Comment: @Såpe I edited the question with my configuraiton file

Comment: @GrenierJ Did you found a solution to your problem? I'm curious, too.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to make your firewall stateless, by specifying `stateless: true` in your configuration. Unfortunately I could not find anything about that in the symfony docs, instead I had to dig into the code and found the [relevant part](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3a02e2103409c58b8ff45c15f44bb8d1f4b3e698/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L617).